# Short story about a cursed family and a standing stone

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is set in a village in Britain, some time in the late 19th or early 20th century. The lord of the manor dies in suspicious circumstances, possibly burned to death. He's unpopular with the villagers due to having brought in outside workers to remove a standing stone from his land. His widow stays in the house. His brother, who had previously been out in the world being disreputable, comes home, mends his ways, and takes over the house. He keeps the widow on to manage the estate, recognising that she's very good at it.

Trouble continues, possibly involving the house being haunted, and the hired men don't want to go anywhere near the standing stone. Two of them are killed, possibly also by burning, and eventually the new lord also dies.

One specific detail I remember is the widow writing cheques to the families of the dead men.

I read this fairly recently, but the story is probably much older. The general tone reminded me of Arthur Machen but I can't find any of his stories that match what I remember.